# Android: Video Record using default camera

Tags: android, video, media, sd-card, recording

Below is my code and I'm gonna integrate with the application. My problem is when the button clicked video recorder invoked and video recoded smoothly but I want to get the response from the camera when the video recording is done every time.

```
public class AndroidVideoActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Button btnVideoRecorder = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonClick);
        btnVideoRecorder.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.VIDEO_CAMERA");
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Can someone please guide me.

Thanks for your time in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing

```
startActivity(intent);
```

to

```
startActivityForResult(intent);
```

Then when the video is done recordng, it will return to your app and you will be able to do something with the video

Comment: startActivityForResult is a good place but still i dont get the results. I'll mark this as correct answer. Please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6968449/android-record-using-default-video-recorder-and-return-the-sd-card-path