# Android: Record using default video recorder and return the sd card path

Tags: android, video, camera, media, recorder

I'm trying to develop an application which records the video using default application and writes to sd card and then return the sd card path to previous activity. Why it is not working for me?? i'm getting cancelled toast all the time when I click back button in the camera.

```
public class AndroidVideoActivity extends Activity {
    final static int REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURED = 1;
    Uri uriVideo = null;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Button btnVideoRecorder = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonClick);
        btnVideoRecorder.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.VIDEO_CAMERA");
                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURED);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURED) {
                uriVideo = data.getData();
                Toast.makeText(AndroidVideoActivity.this, uriVideo.getPath(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            uriVideo = null;
            Toast.makeText(AndroidVideoActivity.this, "Cancelled!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't have to hit the back button - the back button = cancel.  You should be able to record the video, and when you stop recording, you should press 'Done' or something similar (I've only done this with camera, not video), and then it will return to your app automatically.

Comment: camera works fine. But in video recorder after recording finshes it stays on the camera view and there is no cancel button :( any idea??

Comment: No sorry.  If I launch the camera from my app, I click the camera shutter button, it takes a picture, and then two buttons come up - one says 'Done', and the other has a picture of a camera on it.  When I click 'Done', it returns to my app.  I would have thought video would be the same...

Comment: u were correct. Something wrong with my code. I rewrote my code as per http://android-er.blogspot.com/2011/04/start-video-recording-using.html and it worked :)

Comment: Glad you got it figured out :)